# Debugging is enabled in Web.Config but I still get the Error that Debugging is disabled

Tags: asp.net, debugging, frameworks, web-config, bots

im trying the Microsoft Bot Framework. As u can see in the Title i cant start the Application, because Debugging seems to be Disabled...

Web.Config Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And if I start i get this Message: 
[Picture of the Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dK5a.jpg)

Any suggestions? Thank you

Edit: I just followed this Steps: [Link to Microsoft Bot Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-quickstart)

Answer (score 0):

Easy Solution
Just remove the web.config file by right click from the solution explorer.
and then start IIS Express/IIS server/start debugging and a prompt will popup , just press ok/yes.
Its done.